# elasticsearch query in spark rdd

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I need to get elasticsearch document counts by some conditions. here are my considering code below.

```
// way 1
conditionsCountRDD = conditionRDD.map( condition=> /* ES count query with condition */)

// way 2
ESDataDF = /* get es data as DF */
conditionsCountRDD = conditionRDD.map( condition=> /* DF.filter with condition */)
```

Which way is more proper way to get 'conditionCountRDD'?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you know how to query the documents from ES and get it into SparkContext.

If you think, you have more or less similar cluster configuration for both `Elasticsearch` cluster and `Spark Cluster`, I like to think it would be efficient to allow Elasticsearch to query and give you the results.

For basic search queries as simple as count of documents, it makes no sense to get all documents in Spark and perform computations there, unless you plan to do run some additional iterative algorithms/computations.

And when it comes to [`metric based aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) of Elasticsearch, it uses concept of map reduce there as well.

There would be significant IO if you try to fetch sizeable documents from Elasticsearch in the SparkContext and then perform metric aggregation using Spark Code, which something Elasticsearch doesn't have to do, but again you would need to verify and see what fits best.

You may also be interested to see how much Spark computation specifically takes to compute metric based aggregation/count; leaving time it takes to do IO operations aside (which I'm sure it would be much faster than ES computation coz of concept of RDD where all your data could be in memory at once to perform computation).

That being said, you didn't mention/specify the hardware configuration of `Elasticsearch` cluster as well as `Spark` cluster. Perhaps you may also need to employ heuristic approach and see if you notice any significant difference in computation when you do it both ways.

*Keep in mind that Elasticsearch scales horizontally which means it has capability to perform certain types of distributed computations and if it can do certain operations why redo and do it somewhere else.*

Hope it helps!